# Convert Future<List> of custom object in list of object

Tags: flutter, dart

i need support on a problem.
I have a method of my DatabaseHelper that takes care of recovering users from my database created with SQLite.
So I created a class called DatabaseUserHelper that takes care of retrieving information.
Here is the method of my class:

```
Future<List> getAllUser() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.query(tableUser, columns: [columnId, columnNome, columnCognome, columnUsername]);
    return result.toList();
  }
```

My requirement is to convert the result of this method into a normal list.
Here is an example of what I would like to do with Java.

```
List <User> listUser = getAllUser ()
```

Unfortunately, however, every time I try to make this conversion I always get an error.

Is there anything I can do ?
Thank you all

Comment: It should be `= await getAllUser ();` to wait till the data fetched. If you do not add `await` your return value will be a type of `Future<List>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `await` keyword before calling the function getAllUser like below :

```
List<User> listUser = await getAllUser();
```

It is because your function has 'Future' keyword which means the result will be available **sometime in the future**. So, you should wait a bit.

Comment: Sorry but don't function: static List<User> _getAllUser() {
      var db = new DatabaseHelperUser();
      List<User> list = await db.getAllUser();
      final myFuture = db.getAllUser();
      myFuture.then((resp){
          print("Valore resp: " + resp.toString());
      }); 
      return list;
  }